# Add days from a date in timestamp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, caketime

I'm trying to get an date in `timestamp` format and add 5 days on it.

```
$dataCriado =  $this->Solicitation->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id), 'fields' => array('data')));
 $prazo = CakeTime::format($dataCriado['Solicitation']['data'], '+ 5 days');
```

in the book i just see functions to add days from current date. But I need to add in a past date.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If CakeTime works like I suspect it does, you can also give it dates plus relative times like so:

```
CakeTime::format('2014-11-04 16:00:00 + 5 days');
```

See information on PHP's strtotime() https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and date time formats https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php for what all you can pass into CakeTime::format() as the first argument.